# How to use "=IF" in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

How do I write this formula in Excel?

```
=if(700>=700;"Saving";IF(700<>700-400;"average saving";If(700<=400;"Spender")))
```

Comment: No, sorry, don't understand. Can you please give some more context and explain what you mean by "put this formula up"? Welcome to SuperUser by the way.

Comment: I´m trying to find out how to put up the simbols between. IF(700<>700-400;

Comment: Thank you. My english is not my best field, but I´m trying :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not getting you. The formula you have written can be typed directly into any cell except for the error in the last IF - you only have 2 parts to it instead of 3. It would be better if you explained what it is you are trying to achieve then I could lead you through it.

Answer (score 8):

I'm guessing that you want some cell to show "saving", "average" or "spender", depending on the value of some other cell. If that is correct, and the cell containing the value is A1, then the following will do the trick:

```
=IF(A1>700,"saving",IF(A1>400,"average","spender"))
```

If you put this in a cell, the cell will change from "average" to "saving" to "spender, depending on the value you put in `A1`. The formula compares `A1` with 700:

- If `A1` is greater it displays "saving".
- If `A1` is not greater than 700, it next compares it with 400.
- If `A1` is greater than 400, it displays "average".
- If `A1` is not greater than 400, the display is "spender".

If my guess is incorrect, please explain what you require.

Comment: I thought I was thanking him "That was it :) Thank you."and I also want to thank the other people for trying to help me.

Comment: @Heida- If hahondt's answer sloved your question, you should accept the answer (check mark option on your question)   :)

Comment: @Heida, It is great that you thanked hdhondt, but that doesn't get him any credits. Please "Accept" that answer by clicking on the white check-mark next to the answer. This will mark the question as solved and it will give the credits to hdhondt. For the details see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/210367

Comment: For the details see: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/210367)